# How do I return a value of an array based on several criteria in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I have a data in which one column defines the variable, one defines the observation country, and one gives out the value of these two criteria, below an example:

[image]

Is there a formula to return a specific value of this array using formulas, for example the unemployment rate of Curacao in this scenario? I would need two criteria, and I think therefore index+match is not possible in this situation?

Comment: Why is `Unemployment rate` under `Country` and `Curacao` under `Indicator`? Same for `Myanmar`. Are you sure about your sample data here?

Comment: Btw, if all values you are after are numeric, then just use `SUMIFS()` instead of `INDEX()` + `MATCH()` constructs (which are plentifull around on SO showing you have to use multiple criteria if you'd look for them).